# Why does the 2D Gaussian distribution have a circular and not ellipsoidal shape?

Tags: python

I have a problem with the shape of the 2D Gaussian distribution.

I generated two random Gaussian distributions, and I used them to generate a 2D Gaussian distribution. What I expect is that the 2D Gaussian distribution has an ellipsoidal shape, instead I get a circle. Can someone explain to me where I'm wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as special

mu1, sigma1 = 0, 0.1                                  
s1 = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, 10000)              
mu2, sigma2 = 0.8, 0.3
s2 = np.random.normal(mu2, sigma2, 10000)

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Histogram of a 2D-Gaussian Distribution')
bins1 = plt.hist(s1, 100)
bins2 = plt.hist(s2, 100)
plt.show()


plt.figure(2)
plt.title('2D-Gaussian Distribution')
bins = plt.hist2d(s1, s2, 100)
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('counts in bin')
plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its probably just the scaling of the axes. Try

```
plt.axis('equal')
```

for the second plot.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think it was a trivial question, but I've just started to use Python.

Comment: No problem, sometimes the trivial mistakes are the hardest to find :)